# Console.WriteLine overload not writing all arguments

Tags: c#

And another need to figure out a context issue with c#
so I created a class with a overloaded method and now I want to WriteLine all the methods. Not sure if this make sense so that is why I am here.

I want the WriteLine to print out the New test.

```
// this is the class with the method overload
public Test(string make, string model, int year, string colour)
{
    Make = make;
    Model = model;
    Year = year;
    Colour = colour;
}

// this is what I called
Test myTest = new Test("chev", "ava", 2002, "blue");
Console.WriteLine(myTest);
```

Comment: " this is the class with the method overload" - it is just constructor - interesting part is `ToString()`'s implementation which is not shown.

Comment: tried to figure out the Tostring but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override `ToString()` in your class to return the correctly formatted string. The default implementation of `ToString()` will just return the name of the class.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Put this in your class

```
  public override string ToString() 
  {
     return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}",Make,Model,Year,Colour);
  }
```

Comment: That worked thank you. There are so many ways to do it that it get me in a dear in head lights mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have overridden Constructor, not the class method. Secondly, if you want to print all the values of class members (as passed to constructor), you must write your own override ToString method. You can format the output the way you want to display:

```
public override string ToString()
{
       var output = string.Format("The Car Model is {0} {1} which is made in year {2}, color {3}",Model,Make,Year,Colour);
       return output;

}
```

Comment: Assigning the formatted value to a variable does nothing-- you should return the formatted value.  E.g. `return string.Format(`...

Comment: sorry my bad ! Edited the answer.